# Pushing to object in 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to push strings to a 2D array in Google Apps Script but I'm experiencing some weird behaviour I don't understand. A simplified version that produces the same behaviour is here:

```
function arrayTest() {
  var mainArr, subArr, i, arrLoc;
  mainArr = [];
  subArr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    mainArr.push(subArr);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arrLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    mainArr[arrLoc].push('test');
  }
  Logger.log(mainArr);
}
```

What I would expect is for `'test'` to be pushed into whichever array is at the index the Math functions generate - so if the numbers generated were say 0, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0 I thought I would receive:

```
[['test', 'test', 'test'], ['test', 'test'], ['test', 'test'], ['test'], ['test', 'test']]
```

However, this is not the case. What I instead receive is this:

```
[['test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
 ['test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
 ['test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
 ['test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
 ['test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test']]
```

It's clear that `'test'` is being pushed to each position in the `mainArr` at each step of the `for` loop, rather than just the array that is at the index generated by the Math function.

Is there something blindingly obvious I'm missing here, such as an incorrect operator, or have I misunderstood how arrays work? Some guidance would be muchly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are pushing the **same array** into the main array over and over.

```
function arrayTest() {
  var mainArr, subArr, i, arrLoc;
  mainArr = [];
  subArr = []; // <-- This creates an array and stores it in the variable 'subArr'
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    mainArr.push(subArr); // <-- The very same array is pushed into mainArr over and over
  }
  ...
}
```

But what I think you want is to create multiple arrays and push them into `mainArr` individually, so your code should look like this:

```
function arrayTest() {
  var mainArr, subArr, i, arrLoc;
  mainArr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    subArr = []; // <-- Here you create a brand new array and stores it in 'subArr'
    mainArr.push(subArr); // <-- The newly created array is pushed into 'mainArr'
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yep - that's fixed it! Thanks for your swift response.